# Determine CLLocation source from GPS only

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

So the general idea is to get location information ONLY if it is from a GPS source (not WiFi or Cell-Tower). The reason for this isn't really important, for research purposes (and not my research).

If I specify the desiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation, it should be using GPS to gather this information. Is it guaranteed, however, that it will use GPS?

I know you can also check the verticalAccuracy property for validity of altitude, which can only be valid if it is from 3D GPS, but does this guarantee that the rest of the information other than altitude is from GPS also?

Comment: It might be better to ask this on the Apple developer forum where there are Apple staff.

Comment: You may be right, I posted it there also: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264712

Answer (score 0):

I posted here on the apple developer program and got a response from an apple employee: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264712

> Even if it's guaranteed to /use/ GPS, it's not guaranteed to /only/ use GPS.
>
> iOS's location subsystem does not provide a way for you to
>   pick and choose the specific location technology used to satisfy your
>   request.  You will not be able to achieve this goal on the system as
>   its current architected.
>
> Share and Enjoy